# Symfony many role for user

Tags: php, security, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have problem, early my entity have one role and this is sufficiently for project. But now my entity need have many role like ROLE_DEVELOPER, ROLE_COMPANY and when user doing some operation for entity add new role. And how best away for this situation, create new entity or change field role in array or what ? 
I have entity in table user and have one ROLE_USER and now user want to create Team, for team needed role ROLE_TEAM, and how to set new role? Then User want to create client entity and I need set ROLE_CLIENT. If I create ManyToMany relation how my user, who have many roles authentication?  And in user profile I want create, if user have ROLE_TEAM - visible button for go to profile team, buit his many role, I need foreach array roles ?

```
/**
 * Users
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\UsersRepository")
 * @ExclusionPolicy("all")
 */

 class Users implements UserInterface
 {
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @Expose()
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @Gedmo\Slug(fields={"firstName", "lastName"}, separator="-", updatable=true)
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", options={"default": "Company"}, length=255, nullable=false)
 * @Assert\Length(min=3, max=255)
 */
protected $username;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="password", type="string", length=80, nullable=true)
 */
protected $password;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Role")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="user_role",
 *     joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *     inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 * )
 *
 * @var ArrayCollection $userRoles
 */
protected $userRoles;

/**
 * Constructor
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->userRoles = new ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * Get salt
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getSalt()
{
    return '';
}

/**
 * @inheritDoc
 */
public function eraseCredentials() { }

/**
 * Геттер для ролей пользователя.
 *
 * @return ArrayCollection A Doctrine ArrayCollection
 */
public function getUserRoles()
{
    return $this->userRoles;
}

/**
 * Геттер для массива ролей.
 *
 * @return array An array of Role objects
 */
public function getRoles()
{
    return $this->getUserRoles()->toArray();
}
}
```

entity Role

```
/**
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\Table(name="role")
*/
class Role implements RoleInterface
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 *
 * @var integer $id
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 *
 * @var string $name
 */
protected $name;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", name="created_at")
 *
 * @var DateTime $createdAt
 */
protected $createdAt;

/**
 * Геттер для id.
 *
 * @return integer The id.
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Геттер для названия роли.
 *
 * @return string The name.
 */
public function getName()
{
    return $this->name;
}

/**
 * Сеттер для названия роли.
 *
 * @param string $value The name.
 */
public function setName($value)
{
    $this->name = $value;
}

/**
 * Геттер для даты создания роли.
 *
 * @return DateTime A DateTime object.
 */
public function getCreatedAt()
{
    return $this->createdAt;
}

/**
 * Конструктор класса
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->createdAt = new \DateTime();
}

/**
 * Реализация метода, требуемого интерфейсом RoleInterface.
 *
 * @return string The role.
 */
public function getRole()
{
    return $this->getName();
}
}
```

now I crate fixtures but have error:

```
    Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\Role:
role0:
name: 'ROLE_FREELANCER'
role1:
name: 'ROLE_COMPANY'
role2:
name: 'ROLE_DEVELOPER'

    Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\Users:
users0:
........
userRoles: @role0

users{1..100}:
.......
userRoles: 2x @role*

[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]                                                                                                                                                                                                
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Doctrine\Common\Collections  \ArrayCollection::__construct() must be of the type array, object given, called in /var/www/aog-code/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php on line 605 and defined
```

Answer (score 5):

First, you can use [hierarchical roles](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#security-role-hierarchy), so you can add to your config something like:

```
# app/config/security.yml
security:
    # ...

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_DEVELOPER:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_COMPANY: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_DEVELOPER]
```

This means if your user have **ROLE_COMPANY**, he also have **ROLE_ADMIN**, **ROLE_DEVELOPER** and **ROLE_USER** (because **ROLE_DEVELOPER** has **ROLE_USER**)

In case, if you want to have separate roles for each user, you can create **Role entity**, that should implementing **Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Role\RoleInterface**.

Then you can just create many-to-many reference between **Role** and **User**.

If you have any questions, please, let me know.

Comment: update my question and write you chat. How to create alice fixtures for this structure? And necessarily crate new table role and relation ManyToMany or just create field userRole = [] ?

Answer (score 0):

it is possible to save many role in table user fields roles this way:
`{"roles": ["ROLE_USER", "ROLE_ADMIN"]}` (json format) and update `getRoles()` methode in User entity:

```
public function getRoles(): array
    {   
        $roles = $this->roles["roles"];
        // guarantee every user at least has ROLE_USER
        return array_unique($roles);
    }
```